# How do I add an integer of two bytes to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I need to translate an integer into 2 bytes (0 x...) How can I do this?
[image: Click to open]

```
int port = 7777;
byte[] bufferPost = { 0xBC, 0x5F, ..., 0xbyte1OfIntValue, 0xbyte2OfIntValue };
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could add a [mcve] (text, not image) of your progress so far.

Comment: Try masking `Byte1 = (byte)(source & 0xFF);` and `Byte2 = (byte)((source > 8)& 0xFF);`

Comment: is `port` fixed at 7777? are you looking for a "programmer's calculator"? 7777 decimal is 1E61 hex, so... 0x1E, 0x61 - assuming big endian notation

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it may be worth calling out that endianness could be hugely important here; which in this case just means: byte 1 and byte 2 might need to be swapped

Comment: @DmitryBychenko am I getting something wrong, or `((source > 8)& 0xFF)` this will not work, first part is `bool` second `int`?

Comment: @SeM it should have said `>> 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  byte[] bufferPost = new byte[] {
    0x12, 0x23, 0x45};

  int port = 7777;

  Array.Resize(ref bufferPost, bufferPost.Length + 2);

  bufferPost[bufferPost.Length - 2] = (byte)(port & 0xFF);
  bufferPost[bufferPost.Length - 1] = (byte)((port >> 8) & 0xFF);

  // Let's have a look what's going on
  Console.Write(string.Join(" ", bufferPost.Select(item => "0x" + item.ToString("x2"))));
```

Outcome:

```
  0x12 0x23 0x45 0x61 0x1e
```

Comment: Your mask and shift in the comments was far better, IMO; in addition to this being very inefficient, it is also dependent on the CPU running the code (esp: endianness)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I see! Thank you for the comment! Let's exclude *Linq* and do it efficiently